# Extract PDF control and Modified

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I want to Achieve Below Functionality,

I have One PDF and It contain's some Textbox control,now i wan't to extract all control with ID and Value and Modify ID and Value,Now when i Edit this PDF file ( for e.g Add one More text box control )  then old 
Modified Control properties(E.g ID and Value ) should be persist.

is there any  third party PDF tool available for achieve above functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look [iTextPDF](http://itextpdf.com/), you can add things to PDF file.

Comment: I have looked in iText but in IText When i Modified Control ID and Value Successfully,but after that when i Edit this PDF and add one more control then Existing Control Proptrties is changed it not persist.